# Sqlite not work with Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

I have a small project with sqlite and entity framework 6.

I install sqlite by `Package Manager Console`: `PM>Install-Package System.Data.SQLite`

In my `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="demoSQLiteonnectionString" />
    <add name="demoSQLiteonnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=|App_Data|DemoData.s3db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
  </connectionStrings>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

In my context class:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext()
            : base("demoSQLiteonnectionString")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DataContext>());
        }

        public DbSet<Client> Client { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Chinook Database does not pluralize table names
            modelBuilder.Conventions
                .Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
```

When get instance of context: `var context = new DataContext()`,

it shows this error:

`Additional information: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.`

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You Should change the app config file to

```
<providers>
      <provider invariantName="**System.Data.SQLite.EF6**" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
</providers>
```

to

```
<providers>
          <provider invariantName="**System.Data.SQLite**" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
        </providers>
    </providers>
```

and change the configuration file to :

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext()
            : base("demoSQLiteonnectionString")
        {                
        }

        public DbSet<Client> Client { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Chinook Database does not pluralize table names
            modelBuilder.Conventions
                .Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        Database.SetInitializer(new SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DataContext>(modelBuilder));
        }
    }
```